# Enable a dialog button based on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to enable a button on the dialog based on a dropdown selection. Can you advice me on how I can get access to the dropdown in the dialog?

I am able to disable the button by

```
open: function () {
  $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Close Job')").button('disable');
}
```

but I want to enable it when the status is set to "Closed with Comment". The status Id is "status"

[image]

Would appreciate some guidance on this

Comment: Shouldn't `.button('disable')` be `.button( "option", "disabled" );`? See [jQuery-ui disable](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#option-disabled). Note **disabled** with an ending **d**.

Comment: Hi Rafael, it is the same thing I guess, it is a shorthand. It works

Comment: Do you mean, i should change it and it will work?

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you are performing this callback with `open`. This would be executed when the drop down is opened. I suspect you want to execute the callback on `change` or `close` and then check `.val()` of the select element. If you want further help, please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve